# jQuery selector for all checkboxes of a certain class or id

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have an advanced search form on a page and there is also a "clear" button which resets the form. As the form gets cleared I am using this code to un-check the form's checkbox inputs:

```
$('form#advanced_search :input[type=checkbox]').each(function() { this.checked = false; });
```

Problem is, this code resets all checkboxes on the page (tested in Chrome and FireFox) instead of just the ones in form#advanced_search.

The same problem also happens using this selector method:

```
$('form#advanced_search input:checkbox').each(function() { this.checked = false; });
```

I read somewhere that jQuery has some buggy issues with checkboxes and radios, but does anyone know a method or work around for this?

Comment: Do you have multiple form's ?

Comment: The only way I can explain this is if you have more than one form with the same ID. Otherwise, it doesn't make any sense to me. Your `:input[type=checkbox]` selector is wrong (remove the colon), but that shouldn't cause this.

Comment: Check `$('form#advanced_search input:checkbox').length` -- if it's `0` then your selector is wrong.

Comment: @JustinMorgan It is not wrong. It selects all input elements that also have attribute `type` equals to `checkbox`.

Comment: @VisioN: Neither of the two selectors here is used by `querySelectorAll()`.

Comment: @BoltClock It is a simple CSS selector. Native support is used in jQuery: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/selector-native.js.

Comment: @VisioN: `:input` and `:checkbox` are not CSS selectors. Native support is totally irrelevant here.

Comment: @BoltClock Right. I've mislooked the colons. By all means, it can't be buggy.

Comment: @VisioN - I stand corrected, looks like jQuery can handle the colon. But while `input` is a valid CSS selector, `:input` is not. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ndcFx/

Comment: Yes, it's a jQuery selector: http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/

Answer (score 3):

You're not using the correct selector to get the checkboxes that you want. Try this:

```
$("#advanced_search input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked", false);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/R3Rx2/

Comment: That shouldn't cause this issue.

Comment: My selector was not incorrect, this is just one of the pseudo selection methods. 

I've tried .prop("checked", false);, and .attr('checked', false) and all the suggested selection methods here but I always get the same result as my code.

Answer (score 1):

The selector is not correct: 
Try using:

```
$('form#advanced_search input[type=checkbox]').each(function() { this.checked = false; });
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a datatables issue specific to my case. So I'll have to dig a bit deeper to solve the problem.The regular selector methods seem to be working with non-auto generated checkboxes on my page.

I'll update here once I track down the bug.

Thanks everyone!